# Gropuing the data and show the data in table in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJS and trying to display data in tabular format.

This is the array I am trying to format:

```
 $scope.MyList = [{
            id: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d84",
            text: "Data Sources",
            topParentId: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d84",
            topParentText: "Data Sources"
        }, {
            id: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d83",
            text: "India",
            topParentId: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d83",
            topParentText: "India"
        }, {
            id: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d82",
            text: "MH",
            topParentId: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d83",
            topParentText: "India"
        }];
```

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dpzj/161/) about the implementation details:

Currently data is shown as

```
559e2bbc9a496034557d6d84
    Data Sources

559e2bbc9a496034557d6d83
     India
     MH

Instead I want to show data in tabular format

559e2bbc9a496034557d6d84    |     Data Sources
559e2bbc9a496034557d6d83    |     India   MH
```

So far I have tried this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Topic</th>
            <th>Tags</th>
        </tr >
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="tag in topic.myList | groupBy: ['topParentId']">
            <td ng-show="tag.group_by_CHANGED">{{tag.topParentText}}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>{{tag.text}}</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**But I am not able to get the desired output. Please help**

Answer (score 0):

I edited your JSFiddle and put your table in to see what was going on. It looks like it nearly does what you want. As best I can tell, the problem is that you're completely hiding the first `<td>` in some cases. Instead, just hide the text inside it.

Here's my version of your JSFiddle that I think works the way you want: http://jsfiddle.net/4Dpzj/162/

Comment: Currently If a parent has 3 -4 nodes/tags, we are creating 4 rows (with the help of TD). I want to have only 1 row per parentID, such that first column should be the group name and the second column to have all the related tag in same row.

Comment: In that case, you'd need to change your filter method to combine those objects that should be in one row.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this thing even with Css also
HTML where I applied changes

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='TestGroupingCtlr'>
         <h1>Multiple Grouping Parameters</h1>

        <div ng-repeat="item in MyList  | groupBy:['topParentId']">
        <div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden">
 <h2 ng-show="item.group_by_CHANGED"  style="float:left">{{item.topParentId}}</h2>
            <ul style="float:left">
                <li style="float:left">{{item.text}}</li>
            </ul></div>

        </div> 
        <form role="form" ng-submit="AddItem()">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="item.groupfield" placeholder="Group">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="item.whatever" placeholder="Item">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="item.deep.category" placeholder="Category">
            <br />
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Add Item">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle for demo:http://jsfiddle.net/4Dpzj/163/